# How do I make the configuration files in the Jar work

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I don't known how to search for this problem.
It looks something like this:
Both Jar `A` and Jar `B` are `SpringBoot` based projects.
`A` dependent on `B` and `B` is dependent on `mybatis-spring-boot-starter`.

Question:
    1. How to write the configuration of `mybatis` in `B`.
    2. How to configure using `Java`.

Answer (score -1):

Search for *"spring-boot mybatis"* this one looks fine :
http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/

Comment: The OP start by saying "I don't known how to search for this problem." I give him some tips so that I can do it.

Comment: Tips may be useful but this doesn't answer questions explicitly asked. They might be appropriate for a comment, not for the answer.